# How can I reference a Foreign Key from db1 in db2 using MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have two MySQL databases: `master` and `slave`. The `master` db contains the `memberid` field. How can I reference `memberid` in the `slave` db? This is what I've tried using the `slave` db with no success:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `attend_date_temp`;
CREATE TABLE `attend_date_temp` (
`clientid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`groupid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`memberid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
KEY `clientid` (`clientid`),
KEY `memberid` (`memberid`),
CONSTRAINT `attend_date_temp_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`clientid`) REFERENCES `clients` (`clientid`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT `attend_date_temp_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`memberid`) REFERENCES `master.members` (`memberid`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

When I view the `memberid` foreign key in that table, I get this message:

`Table 'slave.master.members' doesn't exist.`

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? [This is the reference I used.](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,150829,200251#msg-200251)
Thanks.

Comment: See this - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Comment: @AT-2016 - I may be missing something, but I see no help there for using a `foreign key` across multiple databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
REFERENCES `master.members`
```

should be:

```
REFERENCES `master`.`members`
```

Otherwise, it tries to find a table called `master.members` in the `slave` database.

Comment: sstan: That was the fix. I even tried that last night and viewed the FK by chosing `alter`, and it still gave me `Table 'slave.master.members' doesn't exist`. But this time I clicked on the FK itself and it confirmed properly. Thanks for setting my feet on the right track...again :-)